# npm builds with no errors but not working?

Tags: node.js, github, npm, npm-install

I am new to NPM and node.js I tried to run this MIT project

```
 https://github.com/quran/quran.com-frontend
```

I followed the instructions of developer

```
0-npm install dotenv --save
1- update the API_URL, in development.env file, from localhost to api.quran.com
2-To start the app,run  ====> npm run dev 
3- Go to http://localhost:8001 in your browser
```

few times I get this warning message

```
'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 
'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command.
```

but it builds the project no other error but its not working when I check localhost address , what am going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it is ```run npm run dev``` at point 2? Have you tried ```npm run dev```?

Comment: yes it is just, npm run dev ,in command-line the  same thing didn't work either ٍ @Sven 31415

Answer (score 1):

The project is assuming you're using *nix and not Windows, since it is using the `env` command which is not a Windows command. You will either need to switch platforms or submit an issue to that project's issue tracker requesting that they make the package.json scripts platform-independent.